# True 2-dimensional scrolling in Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, scroll, scrollview

I'm trying to build a simple macOS app that allows true 2-dimensional scrolling through a canvas-like space.

`ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) { ... }` doesn't cut it; by itself, it only allows *either* horizontal or vertical scrolling at any given time. You can't scroll smoothly in any other direction (e.g. at 45º to the horizontal); it seems to lock you to the nearest cardinal axis.

What's the easiest way to achieve smooth omnidirectional scrolling in Swift/SwiftUI?

(Preferably in a way that is resource-smart and doesn't attempt to render objects/views that are too far offscreen; I expect to have a lot of things going on, and don't want to be rendering unnecessarily.)

---

If you want to replicate this, here's my code—you can start a new XCode project > macOS > App, then in ContentView.swift replace `struct ContentView: View { ... }` with the following.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            CircleView()
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path { p in p.addEllipse(in:
                    CGRect(x: 250, y: 250, width: 500, height: 500)
                    )
        }.frame(width: 1000, height: 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: you should set CircleView() frame not the scroll view frame. Scroll view can scroll only if its contentSize is bigger than its frame size. Please check document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview

Comment: @QuangHà I do set the `CircleView` frame (`.frame(width: 1000, height: 1000)`), and I set the `ScrollView` frame to the size of the window via `GeometryReader`. So if the size of the window is smaller than 1000x1000, scrolling occurs. (Am I doing this incorrectly (or is there a better practice)?) The problem is that it only happens horizontally or vertically, and not in any other directions. But ScrollView here does indeed scroll for appropriate window sizes.

Comment: Ok, it seems that setting the `ScrollView` frame is unnecessary, as it automatically inherits the window size as its frame, so using `GeometryReader` is redundant! I've cleaned up the code, but the problem with any-directional scrolling here still remains.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this in SwitUI, as there is no `ScrollGesture`. You can only use `DragGesture`to drag your content in any direction simultaneously, but I suppose that's not what you want. You might have to use AppKit's `NSScrollView` and wrap it.